# STM32F446 HAL_UART_Receive_DMA writing directly to GPIOA->ODR doesn't work

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, nucleo

I'm experimenting with the STM32 nucleo board STM32F446.

```
  uint8_t data[x];
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, &data, x);
```

This piece of code works when I send bytes to the PA3 and through DMA it writes to `data` the `x` bytes I sent.

However, when `&data` is replaced with `0x40020014` (`GPIOA->ODR`) or the bit-band aliased address `0x42400294` for PA5 LED, the bit for toggling the LED isn't set when I sent a byte to PA3, and `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` may or may not be called depending on `x`. Why?

Link to code: https://github.com/pterodragon/stm32_try/tree/question

Comment: What you are looking for is a DMA transfer from a UART register to a GPIO register, i.e. peripheral-to-peripheral DMA. According to the  [STM32F446xx Reference Manuel](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4d/ed/bc/89/b5/70/40/dc/DM00135183.pdf/files/DM00135183.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00135183.pdf), chapter 9.2, that's not supported, let alone by STM32Cube HAL.

Comment: For reference, I'm following the book Mastering STM32. it claims that only DMA2 (associated with USART1) can do the peripheral-to-peripheral transfer. but only USART2 is associated with the ST-LINK interface so I can't test it through my simple setup now

Comment: Correction: USART2 is associated with the ST-LINK for nucleo-64 boards with ST-LINK.